# What is proof of Basic Hilbert Transform?

Tags: hilbert-transform

Attached is the question. Need to find the output for signal x(t).[image]

Comment: Can I please ask what have you tried so far? Can you make the question a little bit more specific?

Comment: i believe that the symbol "$\phi(t)$" used for the instantaneous frequency (because it is inside an integral and what comes *out* of the integral is instantaneous phase offset from a reference phase of cosine) is the wrong symbol.  it should be "$\omega(t)$" so as not to confuse.  and the **result** of the integral is $\phi(t)$. (i.e.  $\phi(t) = \int\limits_{0}^{t} \omega(u) \, du \qquad $)

Answer (score 1):

Hilbert transform has the **definition** that its CTFT is:

$$
H(\Omega) = 
\begin{cases}
- \frac{\pi}{2}   &,& \text{ for } \Omega > 0 \\
+ \frac{\pi}{2}   &,& \text{ for } \Omega < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

from which you define the **time-domian** impulse response $h(t)$ associated Hilbert transformer from the inverse CTFT as:

$$ h(t) = \mathcal{IFT} \{ H(\Omega) \}  = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(\Omega) e^{j \Omega t} d\Omega $$

You can evaluate the above integral or just use CTFT properties and pairs to conclude that:
$$ \boxed{ h(t) = \frac{1}{\pi t} } $$

Note that the associated impulse response $h(t)$ of the Hilbert transfomer is **noncausal**, two-sided and unstable and its Fourier transform can be expressed alternately as
$$ H(\Omega) = -j \text{sgn}(\Omega) $$
where $\text{sgn}(\cdot)$ is the **sign** function.

Hilbert transformer is most useful for defining and generating the **analytic signal** $x_+(t)$ associated with the signal $x(t)$, with has the property that

$$
X_+(\Omega) = 
\begin{cases}
2 X(\Omega)  &,& \text{ for } \Omega > 0 \\
0            &,& \text{ for } \Omega < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$